# Extraer palabras de una cadena

Tags: javascript, html, html5, angular, typescript

como respuesta obtengo

```
[osos polares] 0 
[oso pardo] 1
```

como hago para traer el resto de palabras en su respectivo orden, de esta forma

```
Hoy 0
vimos 1
dos 2
tipos 3
de 4
osos, 5
son 6
[osos polares] 7
y 8
[oso pardo] 9


let text = `Hoy vimos dos tipos de osos, son [osos polares] y [oso pardo]`;

text.match(/\[([\w\s]*)\]/g)

  .forEach((item) => {
    console.log( item );
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mi me sale bien así:

```js
let text = `Hoy vimos dos tipos de osos, son [osos polares] y [oso pardo]`;

text.match(/\[([\w\s]*)\]|[\w]*/g)
  .forEach((item) => {
    if (item !== '') {
      console.log(item);
    }
  });
```

donde lo que hago es pasarle una búsqueda alternativa a la que ya tenias mediante el operador `|` y donde busco palabras mediante `\w`.

Luego, dentro del bucle, me aseguro evitar cadenas vacias con el condicional:

```
if (item !== '') {
```